# Networking communication sending keyboard shortcut

Tags: java, network-programming

Can I send a keyboard shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to a computer, in order to awaken an application which is stopped by a pause. 
Can I break this pause also by sending a string with the echo service?

Thanks

programming language java on windows os

Comment: Is something like teamviewer or VNC out of the question?

Comment: programming language java on windows os.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an actionListener which receives some command from network and awake the application?

Any communication via the network is basically packets and packet can only contain data. So there has to be code on receiving end itself which breaks the pause based upon some message received from the network.

As such you cannot directly pass a keyboard interrupt over the network. The closet to achieving this (as already mentioned in comments) is something like VNC, Teamviewer etc.

Comment: a car simulation program presents traffic scenarios; during a break, the user has to infill on a touchscreen some formular. the last formular will bring him back to the screnario, which is going to be continued. The formular are finished in java... but i'm looking for the 'signal' for the continuation of the traffic scenario.